# How can I make a cross-domain API call in an Excel add-in, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing an add-in for Excel, using JavaScript.
This add-in needs to make requests to an API (POST and GET requests). I'm using AJAX to make these requests, but the only response I get is the following error:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}.
```

I know the problem has nothing to do with the internals of the requests, since the requests works fine when I use Postman to test them.

I suspect the problem has something to do with a cross-domain POST request. The most obvious cause I came across concerns communication across different security zones. However, ensuring the API server is SSL-secured did not change anything, so this cannot be the cause of my problem. The following headers have also been added to each API response, but this did not change anything either:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
- Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400

I think I may be missing something related to Office add-ins or even Excel add-ins specifically, that stops me from sending these requests, but I can't find more information on what it could be. If anybody can help me solve this problem or knows what might be the cause, please reach out.

Below is the code for the POST request to the API, I hard-coded the arguments for the time being, to ease testing the request:

```
function sendPostRequest(url, headers, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: /*the url to the API server*/,
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': /* the necessary key */,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: /* the necessary data */
    }).then(
        function success(res, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                callback(null, res)
            } else {
                callback({ statusCode: xhr.status, statusMessage: textStatus, data: res }, null)
            }
        },
        function fail(data, textStatus) {
            callback(data, null)
        }
    );
}
```

The fail callback-function is called, with the above-mentioned error.

```
({"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"})
```

The callback-function looks like this:

```
function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        /* a function displaying JSON.stringify(err) to the user */
    } else {
        /* a function displaying a success message to the user */
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the URL is a different domain than the add-in, try putting that domain in the `<AppDomains>` section of the manifest.

Comment: _edit: mostly formatting issues._

Comment: @RickKirkham The URL is indeed a different domain, but I did add it to the <AppDomains> section of the manifest; it doesn't seem to make any difference though.

Comment: @Stphane I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @Elke my comment was about the edit I proposed. This edit only addressed format related issues, like the unordered list not being rendered properly etc.